# "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

I am trying this example of decryption and encryption:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229740.aspx

When I only use the Decrypt method on a previously encrypted file, I am having an error: padding is invalid and cannot be removed

I tried it like this:

```
Decrypt(xmlDoc, key);
Console.WriteLine("The element was decrypted");
Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.InnerXml);
```

It seems that `Decrypt` is not working without `Encypt` first.

Comment: ...yes... I'm not sure I see a problem/question here.

Comment: The problem is that the `decrypt` method doesn't work when `encrypt` doesn't occur first

Comment: @user3068522 It's not a bug, it's a feature. ;)

Comment: cause you haven't use encypt....so you can't use decrypt, you can't decrypt an unencrypted data

Comment: I already have an encrypted xml file, that's why I just wanted to decrypt it.

Comment: @user3068522 that is an important piece of information that you should have mentioned in the question! I have modified my answer. See if this is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some en/decryption algorithms will take whatever you feed them and give you gibberish for an invalid input, but other algorithms simply won't work. This is such a case.

For decryption to work properly, the input has to be in the correct format expected by the decryption algorithm. Encryption often produces blocks of encrypted data of a precise size and the last block can be padded if it isn't complete (see [Block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher)).

The decryption algorithm fails in your code because the padding it is expecting is invalid since it wasn't encrypted in the first place.

EDIT:

If the decryption fails when decrypting an already encrypted file, compare the result of applying `Encrypt` to the original file with the already encrypted XML file. There is probably a leading/trailing whitespace or newline character that breaks the algorithm.